# Can't find wifi on Ubuntu phone

Tags: networking, wireless, ubuntu-touch, phone

Got my new meizu pro 5 yesterday. I live in an apartment building with a lot of different WiFi access points. Mine isn't listed.

On my ubuntu laptop I can find my WiFi access point in a the 'more networks' section. The list simply seems to long. And a 'more networks'  section is not provided in ubuntu phone. The list is not ordened according to signal strength and varies from time to time.

I tried to make my network hidden and then connect to a hidden network without success.

I'm sitting right next to my WiFi access point btw.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Tinus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself.

As I stated earlier there are a lot of WiFi access points. For that reason I decided to use WiFi channel 13 instead of channel 1, because I figured it must be congested since it is a default channel used by a lot of manufacturers.
As you might know channel congestion might cause network collision or lost of WiFi signal.

Apparently Ubuntu orders the WiFi access point according to channel number used, rather then access point name (SSID).

I switched to channel 1 and sure enough there was my access point listed.

After accessing my network I changed it back to 13. Aaaaaand it's gone! Same with channel 12.

After I changed it to channel 11 it picked up my access point and connected automatically.

Mission success!